# What are the Silverlight 3 alternatives to DynamicResource and Element-based Brushes?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-3.0, resources, imaging

I need to have a custom UI element that can be changed, such as the colour and text used in the application but as a resource - in WPF I can use a DynamicResource to assign brushes, strings etc, however I need to implement this in Silverlight 3 - how can I do this as a StaticResource will not do, and as another question I have a resource which is made of other UI-Elements like Rectangles. See example from my existing ResourceDictionary:

```
    <VisualBrush x:Key="Device" Stretch="Uniform">
    <VisualBrush.Visual>
        <Canvas Width="20" Height="36">
            <Rectangle Height="36" Width="20" Fill="{DynamicResource ZuneColour}" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1">
                <Rectangle.BitmapEffect>
                    <OuterGlowBitmapEffect GlowColor="Black" GlowSize="2" />
                </Rectangle.BitmapEffect>
            </Rectangle>
            <Rectangle Fill="{DynamicResource ZuneScreen}" Canvas.Left="1" Canvas.Top="1" Height="24" Stroke="#191616" Width="18"/>
            <Rectangle Canvas.Left="5.5" Canvas.Top="25" Height="9" Width="9" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3" Fill="{DynamicResource ZunePad}" Stroke="{DynamicResource ZunePadOuter}"/>
        </Canvas>
    </VisualBrush.Visual>
</VisualBrush>
```

I have also had an issue with replicating the OuterGlowEffect, but at least this can be done with a compiled DirectX effect so can leave this out if needed.

---

I think Data Bindings will be a good solution to dynamic content as can create a Class which
stores the visual data I need and this can be a One-way binding to update the UI - hopefully this may be useful to others with the same issue.
Still need to replace VisualBrush functionality with something that will work in Silverlight for the given example.

Comment: I think I can use bindings in code to replace Dynamic Resources in XAML, this is an acceptable solution, however still need to find a replacement for VisualBrush.

Comment: For the OutGlowEffect, you can use a dropshadow effect which is available out of the box and set properties to something like this BlurRadius="100" ShadowDepth="0" Color="White".

Comment: Thanks, never too late to comment on a Question, I never thought of using the DropShadow to duplicate this effect, very useful, still need out figure out how to assign a group of XAML objects as a fill for an Object, like the VisualBrush in the example!